# Calling Google Apps Script in another Project File

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to call a Google Apps Script file that is in another project file following the sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805645/gas-authentication-w-urlfetchapp-form-to-spreadsheet) using UrlFetchApp.fetch.
I'm getting the same error that the original poster mentions but I am not having an success with my sample.
Did Google change something in the last 4 years that prevents me from calling the other script file?
 
See script below.

Below is the function that I am using to call the other project file

```
    function makeRequest() 
    {
      var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec";

      var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var header = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  auth };
      var options = { 'method':'post', 'headers':header };

      var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl, options);

      Logger.log(resp);
    }
```

Below is the function that I am trying to call. Additionally, I have ran the authorizeDrive function and published as a webapp.

```
    function authorizeDrive()
    {
      var forScope = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    }

    function doPost()
    {  
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssID');
      var name = ss.getName();
      Logger.log('called');
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to run the Google Apps Script in the GAS project A by accessing to Web Apps from the GAS project B.
- In your case, Web Apps is deployed by `Who has access to the app:` of `Only myself` or `Anyone`.

  - You want to access to Web Apps using the access token.
- The GAS project A and B are in your Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

I think that in your case, the scope is required to be added to the project including `makeRequest()`. So in order to add the scope for accessing to Web Apps using the access token, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function makeRequest() 
{
  var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/***/exec";

  var auth = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var header = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  auth };
  var options = { 'method':'post', 'headers':header };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl, options);

  Logger.log(resp);
}

// DriveApp.getFiles() // This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope.
```

- Please add the `// DriveApp.getFiles()` of the comment line. This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope.
- In this case, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is added to the scopes. If this didn't resolve your issue, please add the comment line of `// DriveApp.createFile(blob)`. In this case, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is added.

#### Note:

- When the script of Web Apps side is modified, please redeploy it as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- If the owner of GAS project of Web Apps is not your account which has the script of `makeRequest()`, at first, please share the GAS project file of Web Apps with your account. Then, please test it. This specification has added at April 11, 2018. Also, please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.